# chromium free c# wpf control

Tags: wpf, chromium

I want to use web page in my C# wpf application but the webbrowser control integreted in visual studio is old and use IE

How can I use a chromuim control in place of the IE Webbroswer control

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try [WebKitDotNet](https://github.com/webkitdotnet/webkitdotnet) which is a wrapper for WebKit in .Net WinForm.

To put a WinForm control in a WPF Window, you can use the [WinForm Host control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

finally I succeed with CEFSharp
It works geart

I tried with WebKitDotNet but it was more complicated